# Jira Rest Api Basic Auth Token - PowerShell - Building with secure strings

Tags: powershell, jira, basic-authentication, jira-rest-api, securestring

I've been trying to build out basic auth tokens using powershell user persistent variables where I store the password as a secure string. This is what I have so far:

```
$PlainPassword = "atestpassword"

$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('JiraCreds', $SecurePassword, "User")


$cred = New-Object pscredential "TestUser", (ConvertTo-SecureString $env:JiraCreds)
$newPassword = $cred.Password

#NOTE: This returns 403 forbidden when making rest api calls with the basic auth token
$header = @{"Authorization" = "Basic "+[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("TestUser:$(ConvertFrom-SecureString $newPassword)"))}

#NOTE: Using this returns a 401 unauthorized when using this for get/post rest api calls with the basic auth token
$header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("TestUser:$(ConvertFrom-SecureString $newPassword)"))}
```

The issue I’ve been running into all along is that I’m not sure how to adjust the code to properly translate the securestring in a way that builds the basic auth token correctly. One thing I noticed is that the actual/resulting basic auth tokens using the two methods above are much longer than what they should be and are not in the right token format compared to the following method:

```
$header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("TestUser:atestpassword "))}
```

I’ve even tested the basic auth tokens in postman and they are failing there too.

NOTE: I have confirmed the json and the jira endpoint as well as method are working by testing with a basic auth method that does work in PowerShell.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What eh.... what is the point of all of this converting back and forth? It's not actually going to "secure" the password in any way

Comment: It actually will if the secure string is saved in a powershell persistent variable. If I'm incorrect, please explain in detail why that's incorrect. Either way, I'd like an answer to my question on how to do this. :)

Comment: @shoppers1d3e: `ConvertFrom-SecureString` cannot give you a plain-text version of your password, which you need for basic authentication - while it does create a _string_ representation from a `[System.Security.SecureString]` instance, that string's content is still encrypted. My answer shows how to get the plain-text password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the *plain-text* password from a `[pscredential]` instance, use [`.GetNetworkCredential().Password`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential.getnetworkcredential?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_PSCredential_GetNetworkCredential):

```
$newPassword = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

In the context of your command:

```
$header = @{
  Authorization = 'Basic ' +         
   [Convert]::ToBase64String(
     [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$($cred.UserName):$newPassword")
   )
}
```